# Using a string of a SELECT query to put in on a IN () condition

Tags: mysql

How can I use an string input as `1,2,3,4` taken from a `SELECT` to put in on an `IN` condition?

I mean, having this output from this:

```
SELECT id_list
FROM ids
where categories = 4;
```

`id_list` is a string like `1,2,3,4`.

Now I want to use that string to put in inside a `IN ()`:

```
SELECT category_name
FROM categories
WHERE categories IN (
    SELECT id_list
    FROM ids
    where categories = 4
)
```

But this only outputs the result of the first value of the string, in this case, `1`.

I know it's not the best implementation, but I'm not the one who made the DB design and I need to make the query this way. This is just a simplified example.

Can someone tell me how con I archieve my goal? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide some information on the structure of category_name and on what results you expected to get?

Comment: Smells like bad design storing relations as comma separated values ?

Comment: I think you need to normalize your db.

Comment: I know it's not the best implementation, but I'm not the one who made the DB design and I need to make the query this way. This is just a simplified example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)**

**Query**

```
SELECT `category_name`
FROM `categories`
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`id`, (SELECT `id_list` FROM `ids` WHERE `categories` = 4)) > 0;
```

**[Find a fiddle demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a60e2f2/1)**

Comment: Thanks for the magic :)